# Let $a_n$ be a non-negative sequence, so that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}b_n= \frac {a_1+a_2+...+a_n} n=0$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a non-negative sequence, so that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}b_n= \frac {a_1+a_2+...+a_n} n=0$. 
Prove that there is a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ that converges to $0$.

We know that since $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}b_n=0$, then every subsequence of $b_n$, say $b_{n_k}$ also converges to $0$. Then, which means that we have $\infty$ members of $b_{n_k}$ in $(-\epsilon$, $\epsilon$), but since all the numbers are non-negative, then all of them must be in [$0$, $\epsilon$). This is where I'm stuck, any ideas?

Comment: That is an immeditate consequence of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2617114/42969.

Comment: If it where not, all of the $a_n$ would  have at least an $\varepsilon>0$ (fixed) distance from $0$. Thus $\liminf b_n\ge \varepsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must show that

$$\forall \epsilon > 0,\,\forall n \in \Bbb N,\, \exists m\geqslant n,\, a_m < \epsilon.$$

Suppose that this were not true, that is:

$$\exists \epsilon > 0,\,\exists n \in \Bbb N,\, \forall m\geqslant n,\, a_m \geqslant \epsilon.$$

In other words, from some $n$ onwards, all the $a_m$ are $\geqslant \epsilon$.
What could you say about $b_n$ in this case?

Comment: Oh that sounds so simple now, thanks!